# why malloc is returing o as default in gcc compiler?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Hi i new learn here please explain below question i m learning on my own from many days   i do have some dout with malloc function .please help i know this site it not for beginners but i couldn't get alternative way to find the solution

```
 1) p=malloc(0) // what  will it return ?when i calculate size using sideof operator   it    throw 4 byte?

2) int *p=malloc(4) // when i scan string it throw 0 why sir?

3)  *p=2   // while p is store in heap
   scanf("%d",*p)//why *p is not possible to scanf here *p why p only?

  4) int *p=(int*)malloc(20*sizeof(int))
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
p[i]=i+1;
free(p);
//now after free i am still get same previos value.. why not garbage coz malloc default value is garbage?

5)   int main()
{
 int *p;
 p=(int*)malloc(4);
 printf("%d\n",*p); // even here i am getting 0 why nt garbage?
 }
```

Thank you sir

Comment: It doesn't matter *what* `malloc(0)` returns. You can store at most zero bytes at the returned address, so it is unobservable. All you need to know is that you can and must pass the result to `free` eventually.

Comment: Ask questions one by one.

Comment: "i am still get same previos value.. why not garbage ... i am getting 0 why nt garbage?" -- "garbage" is not a specific identifiable value.

Comment: Functions don't *throw*.  They *return*.

Comment: Too many questions..too broad.

Comment: @YuHao sir please remove this question from hold i want to learn know things really i know my question doesn't fit here but i don't have alternative way

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, after that, edit your question to improve its quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Freeing" means "making available for allocation again". There is no automatic deleting / overwriting of memory contents because it would negatively impact performance. If you want the area to be set to a value, you have to do it yourself before you call free(). That would be bad practice in release code, though (for anything else but data security reasons).

The same is true when allocating the memory: It does not get set to any specific value, but contains what it happened to contain previously. If you want it to be initialized to zero, use `calloc()`. If you want to set it to a specific other value, use `memset()` after you allocated it. Again, consider that this has performance implications, and is usually not necessary.

As for your last question, `"%d"` is for *signed* integers. For unsigned, use `"%u"`.

Comment: thank u sir please explain 3)  *p=2   // while p is store in heap
   scanf("%d",*p)//why *p is not possible to scanf here why p only?

Comment: @SumitKumar scanf needs address of a variable, Not its value! when you compile using `scanf("%d",*p)`, it gives you warning as `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’`. `*` is a dereferencing operator. so here *p is a value @ p.

Comment: @SumitKumar: Please refer to the documentation of the function you're using. It expects *pointers* as parameters (i.e. `p`). Passing a value (i.e. `*p`) will make `scanf()` write the received input at the *address* 0x00000002 (the value of `*p` interpreted as pointer) -- which is most likely a fatal error. (And we don't "sir" each other around here, relax. ;-) )